# Run-Time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

(im aware of selection has to be avoided, im learning and has got help with other issues that are close related)
Would be very thankful on help on how to re-code below to be more "broad" and as it is now it sometimes runs througt and sometimes not.

It now stops on the fourth line with error message written in title.
Keep in mind:
As you can see, the recorded macro when refreshing databases gives two different types of code, i guess it has to be with my databases are copied when running through different excelversions??? Can it be written in one way? 
A public sub that i can call?

```
    Sheets("DB2 Totbel").Select
    Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Sheets("DB2 Giva").Select
    Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Sheets("TS4LAGER").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Sheets("PIX").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    'Sheets("PIX").Select
    'Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Sheets("OFO data").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to refresh all Query Tables in your excel file?
You could code it like this:

```
Public Sub RefreshAllQueryTables()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim q As QueryTable
    Dim l As ListObject

    For Each sh In Worksheets

        For Each q In sh.QueryTables
            q.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        Next

        For Each l In sh.ListObjects
            For Each q In sh.QueryTables
                q.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, i would like to refresh all Queries in all sheets... But i get this on your proposal...   Compile Error: User-defined  type not defined

Comment: @NewbieExcelVBA Yes that's right, we should focus on WorkSheets. I updated the code.

Comment: When running the new code, only first two sheets´s query will be refreshed.. See my old code above (the recorded one) it will refresh "Db2 totbel" and "DB2 giva", the other ones is  stepped over in your new code... As you can see the rest of them has ListObject before Querytable                                                                                                   Sheets("DB2 Giva").Select
    Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Sheets("TS4LAGER").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Comment: @NewbieExcelVBA Oh yes that's right. In your sheet, you have some of your queries embedded in ListObjects. This means, in addition, you have to iterate also through all ListObjects and there, iterate through all QueryTables. Have a look at the new code.